# Why is concentration never zero for zero order reactions?

Tags: electrochemistry, kinetics, reaction-order

By formula of zero order reaction:-
$$C_t=C_o-kt$$
The concentration should be zero at $t=C_0/k$. But in some books and websites I saw that graph between concentration and time don't touch the X-axis. So does zero order reaction complete or not?

Comment: The reaction may attain equilibrium some point.

Comment: ... and before that, you have subtract the rate of backward reaction from the forward reaction rate.

Comment: In your body, alcohol like many other drugs is ingested rapidly. It is then enzymatically catalysed in the liver, initially to acetaldehyde in a zero-order reaction with rate constant $\approx \mathrm{0.19 g/dm^3/hour}$. This is how you can work out if someone was above a legal limit at a given time before a test was taken. But at long times,  and thus low alcohol the mechanism changes to a more complex one. See Chapter 10 Q11 in https://chemistry-maths-book.com/

Comment: I think you're confusing zeroth with first order.

Comment: @Mithoron no it is a zero order reaction I have checked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the concentration never reaches zero, then it isn't following "zero-order" kinetics, at least not at all times.

If it were, as you say, the concentration would reach zero at time $t = C_0/k$.

A lot of surface-catalyzed reactions are successfully modeled as zero-order, at least some of the time.  When the availability of surface sites is limiting, and the concentration of bulk-phase (usually gaseous) reactants is high, reactions can seem zero-order. But as the concentration lowers, zero-order kinetics don't always make sense.  For example, when there is only one single molecule of reactant left, it seems unlikely that rate of reaction would be the same as when the concentration of reactant was high.  Maybe as the concentration of reactant lowers enough, availability of reactant, not of surface sites, becomes limiting.  That means that zero-order behavior has ended.

But if there were a mathematically perfect zero-order reaction that was zero-order at all times and concentrations, then you'd be right.  Concentration would go to zero at finite time.

Answer (score 1):

There can be the forward reaction  $$\ce{A -> B + C}$$
with the rate of the zeroth order $$r_\mathrm{F}=k_\mathrm{F}$$.

There can be the backward reaction $$\ce{B + C -> A}$$
with the rate of the second order $$r_\mathrm{B}=k_\mathrm{B}[\ce{B}][\ce{C}]$$.

Then the net reaction rate is
$$r = r_\mathrm{F} - r_\mathrm{B} = k_\mathrm{F} - k_\mathrm{B}[\ce{B}][\ce{C}]$$

It can be seen the net reaction rate is of the zeroth only far from the equilibrium. When approaching the equilibrium, the rate is asymptotically approaching zero at nonzero, equilibrium concentration of $\ce{A}$.

Typical case are glasses with light absorption adapting to illumination, using reversible photolysis of silver chloride.

Answer (score 0):

The combustion of a candle is zeroth order. During the combustion, the mass of wax is constantly decreasing at a constant rate. It goes to zero when the candle is totally burned.

Comment: Except you get some wax at the bottom - pretty much Curt's point.

Comment: If the candle is vertical, and burns in a calm atmosphere, the wax burns entirely.